# Scitkit-learn GridSearchCV best_features_ confusion

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I have some confusion about a pipeline I built.  It's fairly simple - consists of a transformer I built called `QueryQuality()` that transforms my data the same way each time as well as a RandomForestRegressor to which I've provided some parameters.  I'm trying to select the best parameters for the random forest by using `GridSearchCV`.

Everything runs fine, BUT when I check `model.best_params_` it indicates that my random forest works best with just 1 feature while `model.best_estimator_.named_steps['rfr'].n_features_` indicates the best random forest has 3 features.  What gives? (Unfortunately I cannot provide a reproducible example at this time.)

```
np.random.seed(2016)
estimators = [('qq', QueryQuality()), ('rfr', RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=50, n_jobs=-1))]
clf = Pipeline(estimators)
param_grid = {'rfr__max_features': [1,2,3], 'rfr__min_weight_fraction_leaf': [.01, .02, .04, .1]}
model = GridSearchCV(estimator=clf, param_grid=param_grid, n_jobs=-1, verbose=3, scoring=rmse_scorer, cv=6)
model.fit(train_X, train_y)

# Check performance
model.best_params_ # returns {'rfr__max_features': 1, 'rfr__min_weight_fraction_leaf': 0.04}
model.best_estimator_.named_steps['rfr'].n_features_ # returns 3
```

UPDATE:
Reading the docs a bit closer, it seems `model.best_estimator_.named_steps['rfr'].n_features_` returns the number of features the random forest was *fit* with, so 3 makes sense.  What was really throwing me is that I inspected some of the base_estimators_ in the forest, and many of them clearly had multiple features in their decision rules.  However, the docs for [DecisionTreeRegressor](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.html) mention

> Note: the search for a split does not stop until at least one valid partition of the node samples is found, even if it requires to effectively inspect more than max_features features

which I suspect is the reason.  Although this is still a bit confusing.